# Best 2d Game Engine for Android[physics]

Tags: android, physics

Which is the best 2D game engine For android game development? I heard the popular game engines are `andEngine` and `libgdx`. Which one is better? Can I use this engine for physics simulation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AndEngine is the BEST. Im currently using it for a project. It has a Box2D extension that you can use for physics. Works excellent! If you have a android smartphone download the andengine example app to see what you can do with it. A new version has just been released.

Comment: i have some issues with the andengine.the inner side of the circle is not act as an wall.so i can not apply physics to that wall

Comment: You need to use a level editor for that.